# Can I check which connection is being used to the query - laravel read-write connection?

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

Is there any way to check which connection read/write is being used to the query ? I am trying to log the query object it returns me both the connection pdo & readPdo but do not specifying that which connection is being used

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    dump($query->connection);
});

$table = DB::table('table')->first();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can try `DB::connection()` to check the query connection

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?